# How to remove a subfolder from URL using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

We have those kinds of URL:

https://www.example.com/public/something/something

I need to get rid of the /public/ subfolder so every duplicate URL with this subfolder would be redirected using 301 redirect to the same URL but without the subfolder. The example above would be redirected to:

https://www.example.com/something/something

I have tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

The example still returns 200. How to redirect every URL with /public/ to the same URL without the subfolder? And if It possible, could you explain the .htacces code which handles it briefly?

EDIT: We have discovered another hidden .htaccess file on the server which appears to be the one we need to set up. Here is its content: https://gist.github.com/zatkoma/6425eb2f93c3c6affd46828de044e95b.

We have added the line here but still nothing happens. Where exactly should we put the line?

Thanks

Comment: Did you turn `RewriteEngine On` before using it?

Comment: @DusanBajic yes

Comment: Do you have access to apache. conf files?

Comment: @DusanBajic we found another .htaccess file, I have updated the question. Could you look into the file please? Thanks

Comment: This new .htaccess already has the same RewriteRule (which should work fine, so something else is wrong). Do you have access to apache `.conf` files? Is your `.htaccess` file located in the root folder of your website?

Comment: @DusanBajic one .htaccess is located in the root and the other one (which i posted on git) is located in /public directory. Here is the one in the root:      

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198033/discussion-between-dusan-bajic-and-tomas-nosek).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your config: the first is that when in subfolder `.htaccess`, `RewriteRule` *pattern* will strip the path to that subfolder
so `^public/` is never matched.
The second is little tougher: your requirement that your site is in located in `/public` subfolder, so when user enters URL without `/public`, you (in root htaccess) rewrite that to `/public/...`
But at the same time you want, if someone writes URL starting with `/public/`, you want it to be removed. 
This can be achieved by checking if Original request (as typed in browser) contained /public. 
So now the flow is:

1. Check if request has /public, if not then add it internally, and go
   to /public (done by htaccess in root)
2. When in `/public` (thus having subfolder `.htaccess` in effect), don't check if request begins with `/public` (because it always does), but check if original request (before step 1). had `/public`, and only if it had, do the rewrite to URL without /public

   ```
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/public/
   RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
   ```